# sl4a permission issue after android upgrade

Tags: android, sl4a

I installed Sl4A via this link : https://electrum.org/android.html

I wanted to run electrum on my Nexus 10.
installation went fine, electrum was working (send & receiving btc).

Then, I upgraded to Android 5 (last version, lolipop I think).
After that, I can't run any Python script via SL4A.

I checked logcat file, I saw some lines about permission & chmod, but not sure if it's related.

Comment: why did this question have -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I just rolled to 4.4.4 and am having the same issue.
I dug into the error a bit more: seems the new "Sandbox of Safety" functionality on Android that is supposed to keep rogue apps from writing to directories they're not supposed to write to is preventing SL4A from writing to directories it probably **should** be able to write to - ie, SD card and such

I moved the files I was writing to to the SL4A directory on internal storage and my script worked again.

I would really like to see a better solution though